# How can I solve a definite integral containing exponential function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> I am trying to use integration by parts and evaluate
>   $$
> \int_{0^{+}}^{\infty}
>       r^3 \exp(-a r^2)
>       \left(c r^{-\alpha}+\frac{m}{d}\right)^{-m} dr.
> $$

So far I have gotten it to
$f=\exp(-a r^2), f'=-2ar\exp(-ar^2)$, $g'=r^3 (c r^{-\alpha}+\frac{m}{d})^{-m}$ and $$
g = \frac{r^4}{4}
    \left(c r^{-\alpha}+\frac{m}{d}\right)^{-m}
    \left(\frac{cdr^{-\alpha}}{m}+1\right)^m
    2F_1\left[\frac{-4}{\alpha},m;\frac{\alpha-4}{\alpha},\frac{-cdr^{-\alpha}}{m}\right].$$
I applied:
$\int f g^{\prime} d r=f g-\int f^{\prime} g d r$.
But I didn't get a result.
I will appreciate any hints.
Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica gave up on trying to find a closed form for this integral ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I tried Mathematica but I didn't get a solution.